# Loading photos onto Windows PC with broken iPhone touchscreen

Tags: iphone, backup, windows, data-transfer, pc

I've cracked my iPhone 5 and the touch screen no longer works. Is there any way I can load my photos onto my laptop without getting the screen fixed?

My computer runs the latest Windows and its a ThinkPad if this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to transfer photos to your computer (Windows 8 and above)

1. Connect your iPhone to a trusted computer using the lightning cable. It is important that the computer is trusted. iPhones do not connect to the computer otherwise.
2. The Photos app should automatically open. If it does not, you can open it using the Windows start menu or search bar.
3. Click on the import button in the top right corner, represented by a downwards arrow in a square box.
4. Select the photos you would like to import.
5. Follow the prompts on the screen. If you'd like to delete the imported photos, you can click on the check box in the prompt.

You will have your photos imported on your PC.

If you have Windows 7, Microsoft offers you Photos which you can download from this website: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/photo-gallery

After downloading Photos, you can follow the steps above.

Windows Vista and XP are currently not supported for Photos.